# how to create web service callback in grails

Tags: grails, callback

I am trying to do web services rest in grails I have examples and everything works just like the documentation, the problem I have is that I have a process in the web service that takes around 5 minutes and I do not want to wait on the client side but time rather that the web service notifies me when the process is finished, I have the theory about callbacks but I can not find a clear example that can help me ... thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the reason the process takes five minutes?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to achieve this, take a look at [Grails' async options](https://async.grails.org/latest/guide/index.html).

One method I've used with success is Promises, this isn't a callback mechanism but it lets you spin off the work asynchronously freeing up the calling resource, you just need to implement a method of reporting errors and maybe updating something to show the task has completed successfully.

This is a noddy example but shows the basics...

```
class MyService {

import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*
import static grails.async.Promises.*

def doStuff() {
    Promise p = task {
        return runLongTask()
    }
    p.onError { Throwable err ->
        log "Task failed ${err.message}"
        // maybe add a row to an event logging DB table
    }
    p.onComplete { result ->
        log "Task completed successfully"
        // again maybe add a row to an event logging DB table & do something with result
    }
    }
}

def runLongTask() {
    // do stuff & maybe return something
}
```